# AWS permissions can't putObject

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

sorry for the noob question but I am trying to upload files from my react node.js application to S3. I am using Uppy and Companion to handle uploads to S3.

I can upload my files just fine if my S3 permissions for 
`Block all public access`
is unchecked (AKA, anyone in the public can use my bucket).

However, I obviously don't want this. From my understanding, I need to configure my

1. IAM permissions
2. Bucket policy permissions
3. CORS settings

I am quite certain my CORS settings are fine, but no matter what I do I can't get my uploads to work when the `Block all public access` is checked. I keep getting a 403 Forbidden response. My permissions are:

IAM:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET_NAME"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::00000000000:user/MY_IAM_USERNAME"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET_NAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

CORS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I've been trying a combination of different settings, but no luck. I am wondering if it is something basic I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explicity deny overrrides an explicit Allow as per IAM policy rules. So if you check the "Block all public access" , which is the default security on a newly created S3, means you are explicitly denying any public access.

> Amazon S3 provides block public access settings for buckets and
>   accounts to help you manage public access to Amazon S3 resources. By
>   default, new buckets and objects don't allow public access, but users
>   can modify bucket policies or object permissions to allow public
>   access. Amazon S3 block public access settings override these policies
>   and permissions so that you can limit public access to these
>   resources. With Amazon S3 block public access, account administrators
>   and bucket owners can easily set up centralized controls to limit
>   public access to their Amazon S3 resources that are enforced
>   regardless of how the resources are created.

[Using Amazon S3 Block Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html)

Comment: I see. thank you. In that case, if I wanted to be able to upload only from my domain I would set the CORS to my domain name only, correct? 

And if i wanted to restrict getObject requests to ONLY signedURLs with the AWS-SDK, what kind of public permissions would I check?